# JBoss SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Getting following error when trying to map `/about` url.
`SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template /about for root resource class AboutControl and the URI template /about transform to the same regular expression /about(/.*)?
13:44:26,051 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Exception occurred when intialization: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException`

To get rid of the error when I changed path to `@Path("/about2")`. Strangely when I browse `localhost:8080/app/about`. It shows up JBoss server properties.
What is the issue here? Has `/about` path already taken by JBoss? If yes then how to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Parent which Controller is extending has its own `/about` implementation.